# window.scroll event misbehaving

Tags: jquery, viewport

As john resig in his blog [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/) suggests that it is a **very very bad practice** to attach handlers to `window.scroll` events, i am just confused if i should resort to this method like the major sites do or show a **load more** `div` at the end of page to fetch more content.

I'm using the following test code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(window).scroll(function () {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200) {
  alert('end of page');
     }
});
        });
```

But what it does is that once the function is fired, the scroller starts misbehaving and on moving the mouse it keeps on scrolling the page somehow.

Please help find the problem and also the best practice for this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had better luck with this comparison:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 65) {
        alert('end of page');
    }
});
```

Hopefully this addresses your problem, if it doesn't can you better explain the scroll behavior that is giving you hassles?

**UPDATE:**

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () { do_things(); });

function do_things(){

    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 65) {

        // Unbind the scroll
        $(window).off('scroll');

        // Log a message
        console.log('do some things here');

        // Wiat for 10 seconds
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Rebind the scroll
            $(window).on('scroll', function () { do_things(); });
        }, 10000);

    }
}
```

Comment: i just checked with this too. As in chrome, once the function fires for the first time, the scroller starts scrolling automatically once i hover on the scroller rather than me dragging it down like we do it normally and in FF it is not firing the function entirely, moreover it freezes the page. I am on UBUNTU

Comment: Without seeing your HTML/CSS it might be difficult to help.  Here is a simple jsfiddle I made, do you experience the same problems when you run it? http://jsfiddle.net/t5GLq/

Comment: yes its happening in the example that u provided on jsfiddle. the scroller starts scrolling as soon as i hover over it.

Comment: Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/t5GLq/1/.  Instead of an alert coming up I put in a console.log().  I wonder if the alert is playing games with the browser?

Comment: ok i checked the second example as well and good thing that scroller isnt misbehaving but nothing is happening too. Please pardon me, what exactly will `console.log('end of scroll')` do?

Comment: It writes text to the browser console.  If you are running Chrome go to the Chrome Inspector to see the output. If you are using Firebug it will show up there.  It's just an easy way to do text output to help debug your javascript.

Comment: its not working in FF although it is writing to console in chrome.

Comment: sorry, my bad. i double checked in FF, now it seems to work but is writing to the console many times than expected as compared to chrome

Comment: both browsers are now writing to the console 20, 30 50 times in just a tiny scroll, even though i've changed that value from 65 to 200

Comment: Thats because the code is being fired every time the scroll is moved.  If the scroll is being moved in the threshold of the comparison then console.log() will be fired.  A way to get around this is once you have reached the bottom, unbind the scroll event and do some actions.  Once those actions are complete then rebind the windows scroll event.

Comment: "20, 30 40 times" - that is the expected functionality.  Look into unbinding and rebinding the window scroll event to avoid the constant firing of the console.log().

Comment: actually i need to perform an ajax request as the user reaches the end of scroll which in turn fire some sql queries, how do i stop burdening the server by using the unbinding and rebinding technique. an example if u cud provide, i'm kind of new to jquery and JS